# Python Serial: WinError 10053 on a hardware connection (DOBOT MG400)

Tags: python, tcp, hardware-interface

I have been programming a robotic arm (DOBOT MG400) using Python 3 and a TCP_IP connection to a windows 10 PC through an RJ45 connection. This was working well, and the robotic arm was acknowledging commands and moving, until I ran some windows updates on the PC. Now, when I run the same programs that have run successfully before, I get WinError 10053 An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine. If I restart the PC, it normally works for a few launches of the program before it starts to get the same errors.
Documentation for the DOBOT TCP_IP commands are here if anyone is interested: https://github.com/Dobot-Arm/TCP-IP-Protocol/blob/master/TCP_IP%20Remote%20Control%20Interface%20Guide%20(V3_4axis)_20240112_en.pdf

There are a few questions on here about WinError 10053, but these are all about connecting to internet services (like email servers) and so the answers don't seem relevant to this hardware connection.

Below is the minimum reproducible example of the code:

```
import socket

try:
    TCP_IP = '192.168.1.6'
    TCP_PORT = 30003
    BUFFER_SIZE = 80

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
    print (f"Connected to DOBOT port {TCP_PORT}")
except Exception as doboterror:
    print(f"Unable to connect to DOBOT port {TCP_PORT}:\n{doboterror}")
    
def send(msg):
    s.send(msg.encode())
    
def enable(weight = 0.196):
    msg = (f"EnableRobot({weight})")
    send(msg)
```

Calling "enable()" once does nothing (the robotic arm would normally enter an activated state), and upon calling "enable()" again, this error message is produced:

```
Connected to DOBOT port 30003
>>> enable()
>>> enable()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\New DOBOT files\MRE DOBOT.py", line 20, in enable
    send(msg)
  File "D:\New DOBOT files\MRE DOBOT.py", line 16, in send
    s.send(msg.encode())
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

So I believe that it is an issue of something like a firewall blocking the connection. I have tried running this while disconnected from the internet, and with the firewall turned off, but get the same results. It is worth noting that this is done on a university managed PC.

The robotic arm continues to function as expected on the proprietary software included with the robot, DOBOTStudio. From this I can continue to make the robotic arm move.

I have tried to recover the PC to an earlier version, but I don't think that the restore point was old enough. Is there a way to suppress any hidden antivirus or whitelist the connection? I am very inexperienced with TCP_IP connections.

Comment: Are you following the correct protocol?  TCP is not message-based…it is a byte stream, so a protocol must be followed to parse a complete message. A common protocol is commands are terminated with a new line.

Comment: Hi Mark, I think perhaps more correctly I am using an API through the TCP interface? The API commands are listed here https://github.com/Dobot-Arm/TCP-IP-Protocol/blob/master/TCP_IP%20Remote%20Control%20Interface%20Guide%20(V3_4axis)_20240112_en.pdf (I will add this to the question). But the commands are not the issue, as it has previously worked fine, and they still do (briefly) when I restart the computer.

Comment: The code looks fine and the protocol looks correct (sent commands end in `)` and received replies end in `;`.  Are you getting a reply?

Comment: I added a new function "pose" (from the same API) that returns the XYZR coordinates. This works as expected, and can be called indefinitely until the "enable" function is called for the second time, after which I get the 10053 error and nothing works again.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Actually, after calling the "enable" function twice and getting the error message, the pose function continues to work. The pose function works by sending a message ("GetPose()") to another port (29999 instead of 30003), and then listening for a reply with .recv(). Does this suggest that only the 30003 port is broken/being blocked? Thanks again for your help

Comment: It sounds like the server is closing the connection on port 30003 due to some kind of error on its side. It isn’t a firewall issue because you can connect to the port to begin with. Can you receive a response from the port after sending the command?

Comment: @MarkTolonen I've tried it just after restarting and later, when it's not working. After restarting I get feedback on the 30003 port (eg. saying that the robot is enabled, or its location). In the second case, listening on 30003 using `.recv` gives nothing (ie b' '), and after the second command is sent, gives the same 10053 error that sending a command with `.send` does. So it seems like the the connection is being closed.